# import SVG file in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

using import statement to import svg files like the following

```
import flag from '../assets/icons/flag.svg';
```

and running the file in the browser giving the following error

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/svg+xml". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

and tried to add assertion like the following

```
import flag from '../assets/icons/flag.svg' assert {type: 'image/svg+xml'} ;
```

and gave me that

```
Uncaught TypeError: "image/svg+xml" is not a valid module type.
```

Comment: You can't do that. You have to use `fetch`

Comment: There is an 8 lines vanilla JavaScript [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) to load external SVGs and inject them into the DOM